# Need help regarding forming a regular expression -xml

Tags: regex, xml

How can I form a regex for xml where it can accept any alphabet except K, I, L or any digit between 0 to 9 and the length should be 1.
Below is one way.
[0-9 ABCDEFGHJMNOPQRST]{1}

How can i shorten this regex?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex should look something like this

```
[a-hjm-zA-HJM-Z0-9]
```

If you want it to be only upper case, remove the lower case ones. This should only give you one character back, you can specify {1} if you prefer but by default it will only work once. Now it would be more useful if you can share the text you want to parse as it would make it easier to give you a better answer and not a hypothetical one.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use xpath to find elements. Then you have the elements and you can work with the string you get. This is not an xml problem.

But its much easier to use `A-Z` in your regex and exclude the one you want to keep.

http://regexone.com/lesson/4